# WordPress Page Walker class descendants of parent with thumbnail and custom classes

Tags: wordpress, navigation

## Please, help!

I'm at my wits end and have to finish this by tomorrow, so I would **REALLY** appreciate any help with adjusting this page walker class. (Please!)

The ultimate goal is to display a list in this format:

```
Animals //not shown
  + Cats
  - Dogs
      - Bulldogs
      - Boxers
      - Poodles
  + Horses
  + Sheep
```

### **Depth Requirement(s)**

On the Cats, Dogs, Horses, Sheep pages, the (Animals) as well as Bulldogs, Boxers, Poodles shouldn't display.

However, on the Dogs page, the Bulldogs, Boxers, Poodles in addition to the Cats, Horses and Sheep page *should* display.

### **Markup Requirements**

I need the following markup in the final output:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list__items"><a href="#link">Cats</li>
    <li class="list__items"><a href="#link">Dogs</a>
        <ul class="sub-tier__list">
             <li class="sub-tier__group"><a href="#link">Bulldogs</a></li>
             <li class="sub-tier__group"><a href="#link">Boxers</a></li>
             <li class="sub-tier__group"><a href="#link">Poodles</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

*There's other divs, headings, etc. inside the sub-tier__group but I wanted to keep it clean for presentation purposes.*

---

### My current Page Walker Class:

```
class Page_List_With_Thumbnail extends Walker_Page {
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul>\n";
    }
    function start_el(&$output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page) {
        if ( $depth )
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        else
            $indent = '';
        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
        $class_attr = '';
        if ( !empty($current_page) ) {
            $_current_page = get_page( $current_page );
            if ( (isset($_current_page->ancestors) && in_array($page->ID, (array) $_current_page->ancestors)) || ( $page->ID == $current_page ) || ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent ) ) {
                $class_attr = 'sel';
            }
        } elseif ( (is_single() || is_archive()) && ($page->ID == get_option('page_for_posts')) ) {
            $class_attr = 'sel';
        }
        if ( $class_attr != '' ) {
            $class_attr = ' class="' . $class_attr . '"';
            $link_before .= '<strong>';
            $link_after = '</strong>' . $link_after;
        }

        // Thumbnail

        $page_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID );

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $class_attr . '><a href="' . get_page_link($page->ID) . '"' . $class_attr . '">' . $page_thumbnail  . $link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) . $link_after . '</a>';


    }
}
```

---

### My current template markup:

```
<?php
    $walker = new Page_List_With_Thumbnail();

    if($post->post_parent)
        $children = wp_list_pages( array (
            'title_li' => '',
            'child_of' => $post->post_parent,
            'echo' => '0',
            'depth' => '0',
            'walker' => $walker

            ) );
    else
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
    if ($children) { ?>
    <ul>
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
 <?php } ?>
```

---

### Bonus: thumbnail output

Currently, there's a `get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID );` for good measure, but if I can spit out the alt, title attributes as individual headings that would be icing on this **nightmare cake**.

---

I've done my best to piece things together found on here (and 4 million other Google searches) so I'm hoping it's an easy fix for you beautiful WP ninjas out there.

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you can convert your data-structure to something which is not wordpress, or at least, give me the tables' structure you have, I believe I can help you (I am not working with wordpress and I am tool lazy to read its docs)

Comment: Hi Lajos, unfortunately, this is heavily intertwined with WordPress' logic that it wouldn't make much sense to extract it (and I will have no way to return it to WP form with the knowledge I have) into a different format.

Comment: You can write a query which extracts all the data from the database. When I was working with wordpress, I was doing exactly that, so I did not have to suffer because of wordpress's sub-optimal functions